# Excel how can I remove number and slash at the beginning of each word in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi how can I remove number and slash at the beginning of each words

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the prefix numbers (aka *ordinals*) go into double-digits? Do they go into triple-digits?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula `=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I used the below formula but is there any same formula to remove it. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677235/how-to-insert-numbers-before-every-word-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()

 Dim CL As Range, CLv As String, a As Long

  For Each CL In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    CLv = CL.Value
    On Error Resume Next
     a = WorksheetFunction.Search("/", CLv)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If a <> 0 Then
     CL.Value = Right(CLv, Len(CLv) - a)
     a = 0
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

**Edit**:

Or this code (only delete if cell value start with numbers):

```
Sub Test2()

 Dim CL As Range, CLv As String, a As Long

  For Each CL In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
     CLv = CL.Value
     a = InStr(1, CLv, "/")

     If a <> 0 Then
      If IsNumeric(Left(CLv, a - 1)) Then
       CL.Value = Right(CLv, Len(CLv) - a)
      End If
     End If
  Next

End Sub
```