# Excel formula. Spreadsheet formula

Tags: excel-formula, spreadsheet

The below is for putting numbers before each word.  Is there any same formula to remove the numbers from beginning of each word in spreadsheet.  This is the link of formula [how to insert numbers before every word in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677235/how-to-insert-numbers-before-every-word-in-excel)

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, i&
    Set cl = Cells.Find("*")
    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            cl.Value2 = i & "/" & cl.Value2
            Set cl = Cells.FindNext(cl)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to address the answers provided in your last two previous questions ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677235/how-to-insert-numbers-before-every-word-in-excel) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388574/excel-how-can-i-remove-number-and-slash-at-the-beginning-of-each-word-in-spreads)) before asking the same thing a third time. Impatience is not a virtue. There are unanswered inquiries that could have led to a solution and you've provided no viable feedback to the responses already submitted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is the third incarnation of the same question ([Excel how can I remove number and slash at the beginning of each word in spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388574) and the second part of [how to insert numbers before every word in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677235)).

Answer (score 2):

use the same code but instead of inserting the number remove it by

```
Sub test()
Dim cl As Range, i&
Set cl = Cells.Find("*")
For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then
        cl.Value2 = RIGHT(cl.Value2,LEN(cl.Value2)-InStr(cl.Value2, "/")-1)
        Set cl = Cells.FindNext(cl)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but showing error when run the above formula

Comment: change the find function to InStr, to search for the position of the first "/"